# NetworkX remove attributes from a specific node

Tags: python, networkx

I am having a problem with networkX library in python. I build a graph that
initialises some nodes, edges with attributes. I also developed a method that will dynamic add a specific attribute with a specific value to a target node. For example:

```
 def add_tag(self,G,fnode,attr,value):
    for node in G:
        if node == fnode:
           attrs = {fnode: {attr: value}}
           nx.set_node_attributes(G,attrs)
```

Hence if we print the attributes of the target node will be updated

```
        print(Graph.node['h1'])
```

> > {'color': u'green'}

```
        self.add_tag(Graph,'h1','price',40)
        print(Graph.node['h1'])
```

> > {'color': u'green', 'price': 40}

**My Question is** How can I do the same thing for removing an existing attribute from a target node?? I can't find any method for removing/deleting attributes. I found just .update method and does not helps.

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The attributes are python dictionaries so you can use `del` to remove them.

For example,

```
In [1]: import networkx as nx

In [2]: G = nx.Graph()

In [3]: G.add_node(1,color='red')

In [4]: G.node[1]['shape']='pear'

In [5]: list(G.nodes(data=True))
Out[5]: [(1, {'color': 'red', 'shape': 'pear'})]

In [6]: del G.node[1]['color']

In [7]: list(G.nodes(data=True))
Out[7]: [(1, {'shape': 'pear'})]
```

Comment: Lines 4 and 6 should be `G.nodes` rather than `G.node` (at least for networkx 2.4)

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that del method you proposed will work.
You gave me a nice idea to build a remove_attribute method like that (with pop):

```
 def remove_attribute(self,G,tnode,attr):
    G.node[tnode].pop(attr,None)
```

Where tnode is the target node and attr is the attribute we want to remove.

Comment: Just a silly question @Dimitris. How should I use your function? If I write something like this: `g = g.remove_attribute(tnode='926', attr='bipartite')` it appear this: AttributeError: 'Graph' object has no attribute 'remove_attribute'