# How do I delete a specific node attribute in networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I want to remove a specific node attribute in networkx.

I know from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47474891/networkx-remove-attributes-from-a-specific-node) that we can delete an attribute from all the nodes one by one:

```
for node in graph:
   del graph.node[node][attr]
```

But I was wondering if there is a way to delete a node attribute from all the nodes without having to loop over all the nodes. Something like:

```
del graph.nodes[attr]
```

Comment: No, there is no such way. You have to go node by node and delete their attributes.

Comment: might be better to test whether `attr` is defined in the specific node before trying to delete it...

Comment: Okay, I understand that it is not there. But for a large network looping through the nodes while also making sure the attribute is there is time consuming, hence I was looking for a quick way to delete that dictionary.